# "query()" returns repeated contacts : Android

Tags: android

`Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},                     // projection
                null,                       // selection
                null,                       // selectionArgs
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);            // sortOrder`

this is my query method. I don't know why it returns repeated Names ( according to Mboile number, Phone number, work, home etc). If in contact list a person "Person1" having three contact number, then I will get three rows of "Person1" with 3 different number.

Comment: Clarify your question please. Is this the case that now you are getting 3 rows for a person having 3 numbers and you want to get 1 row only? If so, which number do you want in the only row? The first number only?

Comment: Yes I want only one number, that should be "WORK" or first number. So it must return only one row for a Name(It doesn't matter how many number or email added to a particular Name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to lookup the contact _id first, and query in Phone by _id.

i.e:

```
 mQuerier.startQuery(QUERY_ALL, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            CONTACT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

...

```
private void startQueryPhones(Item item) {
    Log.d("Start async query phones:" + item.displayName);
    mQuerier.startQuery(QUERY_PHONES, item,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(item.id)}, null); 
}
```

and you will get a list of phone numbers(). Here i use AysncQueryHandler to query, but it's ok to illuslate an example. The important is the correct URI and correct query steps.